# Analyzing possibility of different types of solutions for dynamic programming problems

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I was analyzing various classic dynamic programming problems:

**1. Cut rod problem**

- **Definition:** Given a rod of length n inches and a table of prices pi of selling rods of different lengths i = 1, 2, …, n, determine the maximum revenue rn obtainable by cutting up the rod and selling the pieces.
- **Recursive top down naive implementation from CLRS:**
  [image]
- **Recursive top down dynamic programming implementation with memorization from CLRS:**
  [image]

**2. Maximum subset sum (or better call it as "maximum consecutive subarray sum")**

- **Definition:** It takes as input an array of numbers, and it determines the contiguous subarray whose values have the greatest sum.
- **Recursive top down naive implementation from CLRS:**
  (actually divide and conquer solution, but still non dynamic programming one)
  [image]
  [image]

**3. Maximum non-adjacent elements subset-sum**

- **Definition:** Given an array of integers, find the subset of non-adjacent elements with the maximum sum. Calculate the sum of that subset. [hackerrank link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/max-array-sum/problem)

**Doubts**

All above problems have solution following bottom up dynamic programming approach.

**Q1.** But can we have recursive top down dynamic programming implementation with memorization for problem 2 and problem 3? After a bit of pondering, I feel top down dynamic programming with memorization approach cannot be followed for problems involving a lot combinations. For example, in max subset sum problem (problem 2), we have to consider subarrays with different combinations of start index and end index, which makes it impossible to memoize. Thus this approach is not possible for both problem 2 and 3. Am I correct with this?

**Q2.** Can we have recursive top down naive solution for problem 3? I feel non-adjacency of elements constraint of the problem 3 makes it impossible to have naive top down approach solution (neither like problem 1 nor like problem 2). Am I correct with this? Or we can indeed build such solution for problem 3?

PS: I am just curious from the point of view of logic building